# How to get an DOM element outside of ember view?

Tags: jquery, ember.js

I am currently working on an application where we are mopving the whole application to ember,but as of now the application is working with JSP and jquery.

My problem is that my ember app is currently getting inserted into a jsp page via an **object** tag.now i want to know the class of this  tag and render the route accordingly.

When i tried fo find $('object'),i am getting nothing.

I tried few other options available but no luck.

My index route is loading home route as of now but i want to load routes on the basis of class available on object tag.

below is my index.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

    export default Ember.Route.extend({
        beforeModel() {
        console.log(this);
        this.replaceWith('rentals');
      }
    });
```

and my jsp has this code snippet in order to add my desired ember application

```
var url = "../../rdm/ember/dist/index.html";
                if(page == "user")
                {
                    $(".ui-layout-center").html( '<object type="text/html" class="user"></object>');
                    $("object").attr('data',url);
                    mdmCurrentRequestObj = $(".ui-layout-center object");   
                }
                else
                {
                    $(".ui-layout-center").html( '<object type="text/html" class="userprofile"></object>');
                    $("object").attr('data',url);
                    mdmCurrentRequestObj = $(".ui-layout-center object");       
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you should be able to use normal JQuery. Likely something else is wrong. I don't think the issue has anything to do with Ember.

Things to try:

- Do you mean to use triple equals? `page === "user"` Single equals might be causing weird things.
- Look for an object tag in the DOM if you look in the Chrome Inspector
- Make sure this code that inserts the object is running when the DOM is ready
- Do some console logging to see if the object is really not found, or attribute settings are just failing
- Try including the data attr inline, such as `<object type="text/html" class="user" data=${data}></object>` (wrap the string in backticks instead of quotes)
- Confirm that `ui-layout-center` exists as a class (and not an id, for example)
- Create a minimal example of inserting any other kind of element into the DOM and then trying to set attributes. For example, try to insert a div with an ID and then look it up.

Once you do succeed in getting the object from the DOM, you'll probably need to query and modify contents of the object itself. The syntax for that will look something like:

```
$('#some-object').contents().find('.some-element').text("some text")
```

Comment: When i checked i found out that the element is getting added but it is getting added only after my index route has already set the home route, i want the element to be added first and then the route setting part as i need to set the route based on the class available on the object tag.

Comment: Finally i got it,what i was serching was out of the DOM so i was not able to get it directly,now i did Ember.$(window.self.top.document).find('object').hasClass("user") and i got my element,thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the people googling it and searching for this asnwer, when your element is outside of the DOM you need to get it and then make changes. What i have done to get my element is as below

```
Ember.$(window.self.top.document).find('object').hasClass("user")
```

and it worked perfectly.